# Is it possible to prevent file dialog from appearing? Why?

Tags: html, file, input, event-handling, filedialog

Suppose I have **input[type=file]** element and I want to intercept onclick event and prevent file dialog from appearing if conditions are not met. Is it possible? And why, if - not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Soufiane's code requires that you have a Javascript library called jQuery on your page. If you don't have it, you can get it at http://www.jquery.com or use something in plain Javascript:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="openf" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('openf').onclick = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="openf" />
```

JS:

```
$('.openf').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hm... how interesting, now that makes the whole thing even more quirky. I started from the other end and got confused. I was triggering click event on input[type=file] and couldn't intercept it. While this works as expected on physical click, for some reason it doesn't catch pseudo one triggered through $('.openf')[0].click()... But... only in FF. Chrome on the other hand doesn't show file dialog on $('.openf')[0].click() at all...