# Prevent html input type file from showing open dialog

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-file

To make a long story short, I need to be able to prevent the default action from a `input type="file"`.  In other words I do not want to display the system's open dialog box when the user clicks on the "Browse" or "Choose File".  I already have the replacement dialog working, but the system's open dialog box still appears.

Below is a sample of what I am currently trying to accomplish this.  (PS: I am using Chrome 21)

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 file_onclick = function()
 {
  // Show custom dialog instead...
  event.stopPropagation(); // Doesn't work
  return false; // Neither does this
 };

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" onclick="javascript: file_onclick();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.  I needed to disable the tag and then use the `setTimeout` method to re-enable it.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 file_onclick = function(o)
 {
  // Show custom dialog instead...

  o.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() { o.disabled = false; }, 1);
 };

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" onclick="javascript: file_onclick(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350134/is-it-possible-to-prevent-file-dialog-from-appearing-why

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
<input type="file" onclick="return false" />
```

or if you need the `file_onclick` function

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 file_onclick = function()
 {
  // Show custom dialog instead...
  return false; 
 };

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" onclick="return file_onclick();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first thing I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: The first option did it for me! Thank you!